# Convert Map to Json in a specific format

Tags: java, json, rest

I face some difficulties to convert my Map to json in my java app.
When I convert I have this result `"{\"forms\":{\"1\":{\"dateSeq\":null,\"nomBac\":\"Aeu-C-INT-2A2\"},\"0\":{\"dateSeq\":null,\"nomBac\":\"Aeu-C-MY-1A1\"}}}"` instead of

```
 1 => {"dateSeq"=>null,nomBac"=>"Aeu-C-INT-2A2},
 2 => {"dateSeq"=>test,nomBac"=>"Aeu-C-INT-2}
```

But I want to have a result with key => values or key => {list of values}, because I use this json in another app using php, and decode function need this format if I want to have an array.

My code is :

```
@Path("/listbac/{idService}/{idPrestation}")
    public ResponseList getlistBac(@PathParam("idService") int idS,@PathParam("idPrestation") int idP)
            throws CnrgvSysException, HibernateException {

        List<Seq454> listBacAseq = new ArrayList<Seq454>();

        Seq454Svc sq = this.getS454Svc();       
        listBacAseq = sq.getListeBac454(idS, idP);
        Seq454 un454;


        JSONObject responseDetailsJson = new JSONObject();
        Map<String,Object> jsonMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();

        int i=0;

        for(Seq454 seq : listBacAseq )
        {
            un454 = seq;
            JSONObject formDetailsJson = new JSONObject();
            formDetailsJson.put("nomBac", un454.getNomBAC());
            formDetailsJson.put("dateSeq", un454.getDateSequencage());
            //String etat = listEtatBac.get(i).toString();
            //listCoordEtEtatBac.put(listC.get(i), etat);
            jsonMap.put(""+i,formDetailsJson);
            i++;
        }

        System.out.println(jsonMap);
        responseDetailsJson.put("forms", jsonMap);

        ResponseList listToReturn = new ResponseList(); //Cette classe permet de retourner un tableau de n'importe quel type d'objet
        listToReturn.setStringJson(responseDetailsJson.toString());

        return  listToReturn;
    }
```

What could I do please ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot override the json syntax the object is parsed from server.

but you can take the json string and manipulate it as the following:

```
String newStr = jsonStr.replace(":", "=>");
```

and then do whatever logic you wanted with the other app.